# How can I get the token and secret in Firebase Twitter Login?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am developing an android app using Firebase Auth.
My app should provide a login feature using Twitter.
So I am developing Twitter Login using the Firebase Auth.

I should send the Twitter user's token and the secret to our backend server. But I don't know how to get them.

According to the firebase official documents,

```kotlin
firebaseAuth
    .startActivityForSignInWithProvider(/* activity= */ this, provider.build())
    .addOnSuccessListener(
        new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            // User is signed in.
            // IdP data available in
            // authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo().getProfile().
            // The OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
            // authResult.getCredential().getAccessToken().
            // The OAuth secret can be retrieved by calling:
            // authResult.getCredential().getSecret().
          }
        })
    .addOnFailureListener(
        new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // Handle failure.
          }
        });
```

`onSuccess` callback returns `AuthResult`
But when I try to use below function:

```kotlin
authResult.getCredential().getAccessToken()
authResult.getCredential().getSecret()
```

There are no functions! How can I get them???

Comment: Nice question, btw.

Answer (score 0):

The [AuthResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult) class contains a method called [getCredential()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult#getCredential()), which returns an object of type [AuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthCredential). However, this class, does **not** contain any getAccessToken(), or getSecret() methods. There is also **no** super class that might hold them.

When you try to implement a sign-in mechanism with a provider, there are two operations that you should do:

1. Get provider credentials.
2. Go forward and perform the authentication. If you do it with Firebase, then you should pass them to the [FirebaseAuth#signInWithCredential(AuthCredential)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)) method.

If you need to get the values of the token and the secret, you have to get them from inside a [TwitterAuthToken](https://github.com/twitter-archive/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/twitter-core/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/TwitterAuthToken.java) object. As you can see, this class exposes two public fields called `token` and `secret`.

So once you press a sign-in button and choose an account, you'll get as a result an object of type [Result](https://github.com/twitter-archive/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/twitter-core/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/Result.java). As you can see, this is a generic class. This means that the `data` field inside the class is of type [TwitterSession](https://github.com/twitter-archive/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/twitter-core/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/TwitterSession.java), which is a class that extends [Session](https://github.com/twitter-archive/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/twitter-core/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/Session.java). Now you'll be able to get both objects like this:

```
String token = session.getAuthToken().token;
String secret = session.getAuthToken().secret;
```

Now you can go forward and create an [AuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthCredential) object:

```
AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(token, secret);
```

And perform the Firebase authentication with Twitter:

```
auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

**Edit:**

According to your comment:

> Twitter stopped supporting the SDK 4 years ago.

You're absolutely right. Getting back to Firebase, please note that there is a commented line there that says:

> The **OAuth** access token can also be retrieved.

So you should take a look into [OAuthCredential class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/OAuthCredential), which exposes the [getAccessToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/OAuthCredential#getAccessToken()) and [getSecret()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/OAuthCredential#getSecret()) methods.

Comment: According your answer, Should I use "twitter android sdk" right? But I don't want to use it. Because Twitter stopped supporting the SDK 4 years ago.

Comment: Actually, this question is related with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73331975/twitter-login-failed-on-only-latest-twitter-app-in-my-android-app?noredirect=1#comment129516241_73331975

My released app is failing to login using Twitter.
I got an answer that change the login method from SDK to Firebase.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late update, but please see my updated answer.

Comment: Hey. Have you tried the solution that exists in my edited answer?