# How can I enable searching installed App without queries tag on AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, twitter, android-package-managers

Actually this question is related with this: [Twitter Login failed on only latest Twitter app in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73331975/twitter-login-failed-on-only-latest-twitter-app-in-my-android-app)

I have two Apps.
One is released on PlayStore, other is not (just test app)

Recently, my release app couldn't login using the Twitter Login.
So I created a test app, but it works fine.

The two apps are using same Twitter SDK

```
implementation "com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0"
```

and same function call:

```kotlin
TwitterAuthClient.authorize(activity, object : Callback<TwitterSession>() {

}
```

I debugged the sdk, and I found that the `TwitterAuthClient.authorize()` function starts two activity: OAuthActivity, SignleSignOnActivity.

If the app can find Twitter App on the device, it starts SingleSignOnActivity.
If the app cannot find Twitter App on the device, it starts OAuthActivity.

And in case of SingleSignOnActivity, Twitter Login failed.
And in case of OAuthActivity, Twitter Login success.

When I check my two apps:

- Released app can find the Twitter App, so it starts SingleSignOnActivity and Twitter Login failed.
- Test app cannot find the Twitter App, so it starts OAuthActivity and Twitter Login success.

When I check my released app's `AndroidManifest.xml`, I can find below query:

```xml
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.twitter.android" />
</queries>
```

So I added upper code into my test app.
The test app can find the Twitter App, so it starts SingleSignOnActivity and Twitter Login failed!

So I think, if I remove the query tag on my release app, it cannot find the Twitter App, so it starts OAuthActivity and Twitter Login success.

But!!

Even though, I remove the query tag on my released app's AndroidManifest.xml, the app can find the Twitter app!

Why?!

My release app's target sdk version is 30!

Are there any config/settings to enable searching other apps on Android???

Answer (score 0):

I checked the `Merged Manifest` that can be found on the bottom of the `AndroidManifest.xml`

I removed `queries` tag on my `AndroidManifest.xml` but I can find any `queries` tags on `Merged Manifest`.

It means that other libraries use the `queries` tag on their manifest files.

In my case, I can find the `queries`:

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

And I could find the library that uses this.
When I remove the library, everything works fine!